# "svn up" command says entity too large

Tags: svn

when i try to update my local subversion copy with the command "svn up" it gives me the error:

svn: Server sent unexpected return value (413 Request Entity Too Large) in response to REPORT request for '/repository/!svn/vcc/default'

what could be the problem here?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is a problem with the SSL-certification. A solution is discussed at http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-01/0689.shtml: which said:

> 413 Request Entity Too Large" problem can be solved by moving
>   SSLVerifyClient from the directory level up to the virtual host level as
>   found in Apache bug 39154,
>   http://www.mail-archive.com/bugs@httpd.apache.org/msg21739.html.

Comment: thanks, but i am only on the client side and cannot make changes to the server configuration.

Comment: ok, but it is a configuration error, not a user error. You should inform your administrator

Comment: I also faced similar error interestingly that was with **update** only, checkouts were working fine.

Comment: Just update & commit a few files/directories at a time.

Answer (score 42):

I believe this error occurs when there are a large number of changes being updated and the request returns a response that is actually too large. When this occurs try updating subfolders individually first. Once you've updated a few subfolders the data being returned for the main folder request should be small enough to go through.

Comment: Anyone have a solution when the large number of updates are all in a single folder?

Comment: This worked for me to. For some reason all of a sudden I got this error. Then I made some updates in some large separate subfolders (in fact NOTHING got updated inside those folders, simply no changes there). After that I was able to update the entire copy.

Comment: @RacerNerd SVN up individual files if they are all in one folder

Answer (score 6):

In my case it have been simply a problem with configuration, the LimitXMLRequestBody setting.

Comment: Yes, adding "LimitXMLRequestBody 0" to my httpd.conf file in Apache fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

If your configuration was working before and eventually stopped working, you may have corrupted your working folder on client side. In this case, the following command on your working folder may help:
`svn cleanup`

Answer (score -1):

Delete your working folder and do clean checkout.

Comment: Not terribly useful. I'm sure he's tried that already, or he doesn't want to.

Comment: i would like to see you do that when you have lots of uncommited changes